# Sencha Touch google drive integration

Tags: sencha-touch-2, google-drive-api, dropbox

i'm developing a mobile app in Sencha Touch 2. I need to use dropbox or google drive for storing data and then share that data to a user.
I need to ask if any documentation available for integrating any of dropbox or google drive in Sencha Touch 2 (Android, iOS).?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with integrating with APIs:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/

From the Sencha I don't think that you need anything specific. You can use existing controls like List or DataView.